# How to build multiple libraries under single output folder in Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-3

I have my webpack config as below

```
entry : {
  lib: "./path/to/index",
  sublib: "./path/to/sub/index"
},
output : {
  filename: "[name]/[name].lib.js",
  path: __dirname + "/dist",
}
```

It currently building in below folder structure

```
- src
  |
  |- /dist
  |-- lib/lib.lib.js
  |-- sublib/sublib.lib.js
```

But what I want is both should build in same folder i.e., `lib` like below

```
- src
  |
  |- /dist
  |-- lib/lib.lib.js
  |---- lib.lib.js
  |---- sublib.lib.js
```

And I don't want to make two different webpack config & I don't even want to merge my class in single export file because I want them in be separate.

Any Idea how I can achieve this I am using webpack 4. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround for it here what worked for me
While giving library name in entry object just make your `sublib` under `lib`.
your entry object should look like below

```
entry : {
  lib: "./path/to/index",
  "lib/sublib": "./path/to/sub/index"
}
```

so this will export your `sublib` in `lib` folder.
this will be very helpful when have written a Jenkins jobs to pic library from `lib` folder to publish in your `npm` repo